# /tag Regular expression in Python /tag My code below doesn't recognize the pattern

Tags: python, regex

My regular expression in Python below doesn't see the pattern. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

================

```
import re

l = 'rootfs on / type rootfs (rw xyz'
m_obj = re.match(r'on / type .*? \(rw', l)

if m_obj:
    print "Found!"
else:
    print "Not found!"
```

=================

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match`, start matching from the beginning of string

you need to use `search`. It should be:

```
re.search(r'on / type .*? \(rw', l)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the documentation of the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) - especially the difference between `match` and `search`. what you should use here is `search` (your regex does not match the whole string):

```
import re

l = 'rootfs on / type rootfs (rw xyz'
m_obj = re.search(r'on / type .*? \(rw', l)

if m_obj:
    print "Found!"
else:
    print "Not found!"
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact `match` starts from the beginning of string- so try

```
import re

l = 'rootfs on / type rootfs (rw xyz'
m_obj = re.match(r'.*?on / type .*? \(rw', l)

if m_obj:
    print "Found!"
else:
    print "Not found!"
```